# Position label above text field in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uilabel, uinavigationbar

Edit: I achieved what I wanted by adding the label as a subview of the titleView, but it's not perfect. I constrained the label's bottom anchor to the title view's top anchor. I also constrained the label's center x anchor with the title view's center x anchor. Despite this it still looks slightly off center. Also, on non-notched devices, the label is not visible in landscape.

---

I have a `UILabel` I'd like to position above or below (preferably above) a `UITextField` that is set as the `titleView` of my app's navigation bar. I tried anchoring the label's top anchor to the text field's bottom anchor, like this,

```
 titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.addressBar.bottomAnchor)
```

(this is inside `NSLayoutConstraint.activate`)

but I get a crash at runtime when I try to do this.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600003c84680 "UILabel:0x7fe7f8421970.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600003c846c0 "UITextField:0x7fe7f842f700.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Currently I have the label's top anchor anchored to the bottom anchor of the `topLayoutGuide`. This puts the label below the navigation bar, which isn't ideal. The UI is done entirely in Swift code, without IB. The creation of both the label and the text field are done in the `loadView` method, along with the constraints.

Here's the relevant code in my loadView method:

```
        addressBar = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width)!, height: 30))
        navigationItem.titleView = addressBar
        
        titleLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
//            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.addressBar.bottomAnchor),
            titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            // More constraints...
        ])
```

Other attributes of the text field and label are set later in the `viewDidLoad` method.

This is my first real app that I've done the UI entirely in code, so this is still new to me. I've always used IB in the past. I tried researching this, but I wasn't able to find exactly what I want to do. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: "distance that you want"), you want to add down of navigation bar?.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I accomplished this. First added the label as a subview of the titleView like this:

```
navigationItem.titleView?.addSubview(titleLabel)
```

I then added these two constraints, inside `NSLayoutConstraint.activate`

```
titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationItem.titleView!.topAnchor)
titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationItem.titleView!.centerXAnchor)
```

It's not perfect, despite the center x anchor constraint it still looks slightly off center.

Here's the complete code, all of this is in the `loadView` method. (The label is declared as a UILabel in the Swift class above the `loadView` method.)

```
titleLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
navigationItem.titleView?.addSubview(titleLabel)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationItem.titleView!.topAnchor),
            titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationItem.titleView!.centerXAnchor)
        ])
```

You can set things like font color and text alignment later in the `viewDidLoad` method.